# ASP.NET C# - Data binding on a object attribute that is within another object

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, objectdatasource, detailsview

I'm having an hard time trying to bind an attribute within a DetailsView EditTemplateField. Here goes my data structure:

```
Class1{
public int idClass { get; set; }
public Class2 classObject { get; set; }

}

Class2 {
public int idClass2 { get; set;}
}
```

The Class1 is the ObjectDataSource DataObjectTypeName associated to the dropdownlist.
I'm trying to bind a Dropdownlist Value to the idClass2 like this:

```
Bind("classObject.idClass2");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. AFAIK you can only use Eval (one way binding) with nested objects. Anyway what you can do is to modify the first class with a new property:

```
Class1{
  public int idClass { get; set; }
  public Class2 classObject { get; set; }

  public int idClass2 { 
    get { return classObject.idClass2; }
    set { classObject.idClass2 = value; }
  }
}
```

and bind it: `Bind(idClass2)`

Answer (score 0):

Is it absolutely necessary to have the idClass2 in a separate class? if this is the only property in Class2, why dont you just add the property to the Class1?

Even though you

Otherwise I think you need to extract the object Class2 and then bind it like this

```
var _classObject = class1.classObject;
Bind("_classObject.idClass2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a "plain" object

```
Class1{
    public Class2 class2 { get; set; }
    public int Var { get; set; }
    public int InnerVar { get { return class2.Var; } }
}

Class2{
    public int Var { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use the Class1 InnerVar to access to Var in Class2.

Answer (score 0):

when you make an object of `classObject` you should also make objects of all the classes that are lying in it. in this way you can access `classObject.idClass2` , if you dont make object of `idClass2` you'll get Null Exception.